# iOS Push Notification on Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to setup Azure Push Notifications for iOS app using Swift. I followed the documentation provided here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push.

Here is my ClientManager

```
class ClientManager {
    static let sharedClient = MSClient(applicationURLString: "https://ar-todo.servicebus.windows.net:443")
}
```

As per the documentation I have replaced %AppUrl% with the URL of my Azure Mobile App backend. But I get the following error when my device tries to register for Push Notification.

> Error registering for notifications:  Optional("Error
>   Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1302
>   \"`401`Missing authorization
>   token.TrackingId:a027aaec-887d-49c3-acf7-00d1503fd94b_G4,TimeStamp:2/14/2016
>   10:19:48 PM\"
>   UserInfo={com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey= { URL:
>   https://ar-todo.servicebus.windows.net:443/push/installations/F3C97DFA-2B7A-4DDE-902A-45A2C5C48305
>   },
>   com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorResponseKey= { URL:
>   https://ar-todo.servicebus.windows.net:443/push/installations/F3C97DFA-2B7A-4DDE-902A-45A2C5C48305
>   } { status code: 401, headers {\n    \"Content-Type\" =
>   \"application/xml; charset=utf-8\";\n    Date = \"Sun, 14 Feb 2016
>   22:19:47 GMT\";\n    Server = \"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\";\n
>   \"Transfer-Encoding\" = Identity;\n} },
>   NSLocalizedDescription=`401`Missing
>   authorization
>   token.TrackingId:a027aaec-887d-49c3-acf7-00d1503fd94b_G4,TimeStamp:2/14/2016
>   10:19:48 PM}")

I'm sure that my AppURL is missing some information. Can someone successful in configuring this shed some light?

Comment: For push notification from notification hub.  You can simply follow 

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started

For using it in Swift Project
Make sure you add bridging header in your project and import correct file name

#import "WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the App Service URL matches the one in the Azure portal (if you could post a screenshot, that would be awesome).

One thing that stands out is that you are **using a port number at the end** of the URL. Remove it and try running the app again.

Answer (score 0):

You have the URL for your Notification Hub in your MSClient constructor, where it should have the URL for your Mobile App instead. From the page you linked:

> Add file ClientManager.swift with the following contents. Replace
>   %AppUrl% with the URL of the Azure Mobile App backend.
>
> ```
> class ClientManager {
>     static let sharedClient = MSClient(applicationURLString: "%AppUrl%")
> }
> ```